# Jenkins TortoiseSVN and Post Commit Hook

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I am trying to push the change notification from the SVN to the jenkins via post commit hook.
However there is one thing I am confused.

The literature says that the post commit hook should be configured on the SVN server. To which I have no access.

There is a way to configure post commit hook on the TortoiseSVN (Windows client which we use).

As per the TortoiseSVN help page:

> This dialog allows you to set up hook scripts which will be executed automatically when certain Subversion actions are performed. As opposed to the hook scripts explained in the section called “Server side hook scripts”, these scripts are executed locally on the client.

I was thinking if is it possible that I run a post build script locally on the developer machine which reaches out to Jenkins directly (By passing SVN) telling it that time to check out the code from the SVN. This will allow me to avoid asking the IT team to do anything on SVN server actually.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: You really need to have the server trigger Jenkins, not depend upon a developer workstation setup. It's the most reliable way to make it work. There's a reason the Jenkins literature says to do it there.

Comment: Other than this the only option is to somehow make SVN plugin in Jenkins monitor a branch but not to check out the code actually. And whatever googling I did, looks like it is not possible.
SVN box remains out of my hands. They will not change anything because it will set off a long chain related work for them.

Comment: If the people responsible for supporting the environment refuse to do the work of supporting the environment, it's time to get management involved. They are actively preventing other people from doing their jobs effectively, and that is a **huge** problem. Don't work around their laziness - fix the root problem.